# Three consecutive numbers in a while loop

Tags: java

Write a program that reads integers from the user until he enters -1, and print “Consecutive ” if there are three consecutive numbers otherwise print “None Consecutive”; that is in the number list you read are in an order such that there is some integer k that the numbers values are k, k+1, and k+2.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = x + 1;
    int z = x + 2;
    boolean areConsecutive = false;

    while (x != -1) {
        if (x == y) {
            x = scan.nextInt();
            if (x == z)
                areConsecutive = true;
        }
        x = scan.nextInt();
    }
    if (areConsecutive)
        System.out.print("Consecutive");
    else
        System.out.print("None Consecutive");
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: you need to update `y` and `z` values afer every iteration

Comment: but I'm giving x a new value every time, so wouldn't y and z change as x intakes new values? For example if x was 4 at first, then I gave it a new value 5, wouldn't y switch from being 5 (4+1) to 6(5+1)? and the same for z.

Comment: Not, they are primitive types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next integer before checking with y, then check for z. if one of these fails update y and z and check again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = x + 1;
    int z = x + 2;
    boolean areConsecutive = false;

    while (x != -1) {
        x = scan.nextInt();
        if (x == y) {
            x = scan.nextInt();
            if (x == z)
                areConsecutive = true;
        }
        y = x + 1;
        z = x + 2;
    }
    if (areConsecutive)
        System.out.print("Consecutive");
    else
        System.out.print("None Consecutive");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close but you're not maintaining the history of the numbers correctly.

First, to clarify, the specification calls for you to enter an arbitrary quantity of *arbitrary* numbers from the user and simply check if any three of them are consecutive. Hence the first line below would have a consecutive sequence (the `1 2 3` bit starting at the third number) but the second would not:

```
9 9 1 2 3 9
3 1 4 1 5 9
```

One way to do this is simply maintain the *minimal* information to detect a consecutive sequence. To do that, you need to keep a copy of only the last three numbers entered. The pseudo-code (easily transformable into any procedural language) for such a beast would be:

```
# Get first number, ensure no chance of consecutive
# sequence until at least three are entered.

num3 = getint()
num2 = num3       
num1 = num3
consecutive = false

# Loop until -1 entered.

while num3 != -1:
    # Check for consecutive sequence.

    if (num1 + 1 == num2) and (num2 + 1 == num3):
        consecutive = true

    # Shift numbers "left".

    num1 = num2
    num2 = num3
    num3 = getint()

if consecutive:
     print "Consecutive"
else
    print "None Consecutive"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment y and z by 1 before scaning new x.
This is what you are looking for:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        boolean areConsecutive = false;

        while (x != -1) {
            int y = x + 1;
            System.out.println("enter");
            x = scan.nextInt();
            if (x == y) {
                System.out.println("enter");
                int z = x + 1;
                x = scan.nextInt();
                if (x == z)
                    areConsecutive = true;
            }
        }
        if (areConsecutive)
            System.out.println("Consecutive");
        else
            System.out.println("None Consecutive");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, we have to check if three numbers are consecutive no matter the order they were entered by user:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){ 

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int[3];

    for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();

    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    boolean areConsecutive = true;

    for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; ++i)
        if(numbers[i+1] - numbers[i] != 1)
              areConsecutive = false;

    if(areConsecutive)
     System.out.print("Consecutive");
    else
     System.out.print("None Consecutive");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scan.nextInt();
int y = scan.nextInt();
int z = scan.nextInt();
boolean areConsecutive = false;

while ((x != -1)&&(y != -1)&&(z != -1)){
    if ((z == y + 1)&&(y == x + 1)
            areConsecutive = true;
if (areConsecutive)
    System.out.print("Consecutive");
else
    System.out.print("None Consecutive");
}
```